# Traverse nested Javascript arrays to create paths

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array, mutual-recursion

I have an arbitrarily nested data structure like this -

```
var nested = [ 'a', [ [ 'b' ], [ 'c' ] ] ];
```

I would like to traverse the levels to create an array of arrays like this

```
var paths = [['a', 'b'] ['a', 'c']];
```

I know this is going to take recursion. Any ideas?!

Comment: Despite your lack of attempt, I would like to see this answer as well.

Comment: So the first item in the array defines the name and the second item, if present, is another array of its children?

Comment: @minitech: That's how it seems to me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/4LPVL/ this isn't exactly what you are looking for, but I happened to have a few functions laying around that may offer some insight on a solution for you

Comment: @minitech - yes that is correct - the structure could apply to say a folder structure or something (each folder being empty but able to have children)

Comment: Thanks @rlemon - am having a play with your functions

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but here is an interesting function taken from [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan/blob/2a15b901331147d1a7ca30a33f662d15bc355bc8/src/generic/iterator.js) that you might be able to modify for your need.

Note that some assumptions about the input are being made that you didn't specify

```js
const iterate = (tree, cb) => {
  const stack = [tree];
  const parent = [null];
  const count = [];
  const depth = [];
  const path = [];
  let idx = 0;
  let inc = true;

  while (idx !== -1) {
    const e = stack[idx];
    if (e instanceof Set) {
      stack[idx] = [...e];
      stack[idx].or = true;
    } else if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      if (e.or !== true) {
        stack.splice(idx, 1, ...e);
        parent.splice(idx, 1, ...new Array(e.length).fill(parent[idx]));
        if (parent[idx] !== null) {
          depth[parent[idx]] += e.length - 1;
        }
      } else {
        if (count[idx] === undefined) {
          count[idx] = 0;
          depth[idx] = 0;
        } else if (depth[idx] !== 0) {
          stack.splice(idx + 1, depth[idx]);
          parent.splice(idx + 1, depth[idx]);
          depth[idx] = 0;
        }

        if (count[idx] < e.length) {
          stack.splice(idx + 1, 0, e[count[idx]]);
          parent.splice(idx + 1, 0, idx);
          count[idx] = (count[idx] || 0) + 1;
          depth[idx] += 1;
          inc = true;
          idx += 1;
        } else {
          count[idx] = 0;
          idx -= 1;
        }
      }
    } else if (inc === true) {
      path.push(e);
      cb('ADD', e);
      if (idx === stack.length - 1) {
        cb('FIN', path);
        inc = false;
      } else {
        idx += 1;
      }
    } else {
      cb('RM', path.pop());
      idx -= 1;
    }
  }
};

const extract = (tree) => {
  const result = [];
  iterate(tree, (type, p) => {
    if (type === 'FIN') {
      result.push([...p]);
    }
  });
  return result;
};

console.log(extract(['a', new Set([['b'], ['c']])]));
// => [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'a', 'c' ] ]

console.log(extract(['a', new Set([['b', new Set(['d', 'e'])], ['c']])]));
// => [ [ 'a', 'b', 'd' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'e' ], [ 'a', 'c' ] ]

console.log(extract(['a', new Set([['b'], ['c']]), 'd']));
// => [ [ 'a', 'b', 'd' ], [ 'a', 'c', 'd' ] ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```